# When is pybind11 Keep Alive needed?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to understand the Keep Alive (`py::keep_alive`) feature of pybind11.  Specifically under what circumstances it needs to be used.  The documentation provides this example:

> Consider the following example: here, the binding code for a list append operation ties the lifetime of the newly added element to the underlying container:
>
> ```
> py::class_<List>(m, "List")
>    .def("append", &List::append, py::keep_alive<1, 2>());
> ```

In this example, what might the C++ class definition of `List` and its member function `append` look like?

Like, if we were wrapping `std::vector`, would we need to specify `py:keep_alive` on `push_back` for example?  Or is this hypothetical `List::append` doing something weird/different?